# vi command line editing key bindings - previous command

Tags: command-line, vi

I use the vi editor on the command line, and I really like it.

I use

```
set -o vi
```

to set the bindings.

The only thing is that I have to use the up and down arrows to cycle through the 
previous executed commands.

In the emacs key bindings it was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to get to the previous command. It is the one emacs binding I miss.
I have been looking for something like it vi - but can't find it. My search gets diverted to the text editing vi binding for previous command which is held in " : "  or hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to get a command window. I am using vi on the command line instead of emacs. There has to be something.

Is there something comparable in the vi command line ?

Using the <kbd>Up</kbd> / <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow keys is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the answer on this on this site:

[Working Productively in Bash's Vi Command Line Editing Mode (with Cheat Sheet)](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet/)

Make sure set -o vi is set to 'on'. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> or escape to get to command mode. Then tap <kbd>k</kbd> go up the history and <kbd>j</kbd> to go down. It is so intuitive that I imagine most vi power-users discover it without trying, without help.

Thanks.